# returning stuff from custom commands cypress

Tags: cypress

I created the below function but im having great difficulties in getting stuff returned from the last if block (elArr[3]).

It works fine if i remove all the return statements and say put: cy.get(el).click() in the if blocks but i dont want to have that command in this function but performed in the test instead like this:

`cy.traverseIFrame(['1', '2', '3'], 'myelement').click()`

can someone help me out it is driving me crazy trying to get this working.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('traverseIFrame', (elArr, searchEl) => {
 return cy.iframe(elArr[0]).within((res) => {
    if (res.find(searchEl).length > 0) {
      console.log('true1');
      cy.get(searchEl).click(150, 220, {
        force: true
      });
    }
    return cy.iframe(elArr[1]).within((res) => {
      if (res.find(searchEl).length > 0) {
        console.log('true2');
        cy.get(searchEl).click(150, 220, {
          force: true
        });
      }
      return cy.iframe(elArr[2]).within((res) => {
        if (res.find(searchEl).length > 0) {
          console.log('true3');
          cy.get(searchEl).click(150, 220, {
            force: true
          });
        }
        return cy.iframe(elArr[3]).within((res) => {
          if (res.find(searchEl).length > 0) {
            console.log('true4');
            return cy.get(searchEl);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `.within()` commands pays no attention to inner `return`, but gives back the previous subject

[within#Yields](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within#Yields)

> .within() yields the same subject it was given from the previous command.
> Trying to return a different element the .within callback have no effect

Instead, an equivalent should be `.then()` & `cy.wrap(...).find(...)` combo,

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('traverseIFrame', (elArr, searchEl) => {
  return cy.iframe(elArr[0]).then(res => {

    // this find sb ok since it's jquery
    if (res.find(searchEl).length > 0) {
      console.log('true1');

      // cy.wrap().find() here equates to .within(() => cy.get()
      cy.wrap(res).find(searchEl).click(150, 220, { force: true });    
    }

    // this nested cy.iframe may be ok - depends on internals of this command
    return cy.iframe(elArr[1]).then((res) => {
      ...

      // inner-most return
      return cy.wrap(res).find(searchEl)
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond I will take a look to see if that works!